# Run two shell commands

Tags: bash, shell, unix

What would be the correct format for the following, where I want to execute two scripts? The following is only executing the first one for me:

```
if ps aux | grep -E "[a]ffiliate_download.py|[g]oogle_download.py" > /dev/null
then
    echo "Script is already running. Skipping"
else
    exec "$DIR/affiliate_download.py"
    exec "$DIR/google_download.py"
fi
```

Comment: Do you mean it's only running the first command when reaching `else`?

Comment: @kaybee99, `exec` causes the shell to replace itself with the process to be run, so that's normal/expected behavior here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `exec` command replaces the current shell process with the program it runs. Since the shell is no longer running, it can't run commands after that.

Just execute the commands normally:

```
else
    "$DIR/affiliate_download.py"
    "$DIR/google_download.py"
fi
```

Comment: What is the difference between doing `exec "command"` and `"command"` ?

Comment: @David542, the difference is that `exec` replaces the shell's process table entry with the new command -- so the shell is no longer running, and signals sent to its PID are received by the program it's replaced with.

Comment: @David542 When you run a program normally, it's run in a new process, and the shell waits for it to finish (or doesn't wait if you put it into the background with `&`). When you run it with `exec`, it run's in the shell's process, completely replaceing the shell.

Comment: @David542:  Without `exec` when `"command"` is an external program, the shell does a `fork` first.  This creates a new shell process when it can mess with things like redirections.  Then an `exec` is done to replace the current *program* with a different one, in the same *process*.  Certain things survive an `exec` by default, for example the environment block, the file descriptor table, and   the uid.  See also the `env` program (`man env`).